# Running php migrate through docker

Tags: laravel, docker

I am trying to run `php artisan migrate` on docker compose but this error occur in my mysql container:

```
sh: php: command not found
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    # Application & web server
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - "mysql"
        ports:
            - 8001:80
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        entrypoint: sh -c "sleep 30 && php artisan migrate"
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        ports:
            - 9001:80
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
#Docker Networks
networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

Docker file

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql -j$(nproc) gd \
    && apt-get autoclean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Update apache conf to point to application public directory
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Update uploads config
RUN echo "file_uploads = On\n" \
         "memory_limit = 1024M\n" \
         "upload_max_filesize = 512M\n" \
         "post_max_size = 512M\n" \
         "max_execution_time = 1200\n" \
         > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

# Enable headers module
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` image only contains the database.  The `entrypoint:` setting says "run this command instead of what the container would have normally run, ignoring even its default setup".  Since you've attached the `entrypoint:` to the `database:`, you try to run `php artisan migrate` instead of running MySQL, and you run it in a database-only image.

The migration step needs to be attached to your application container, not the database container.  I tend to write this as an *entrypoint wrapper script*, a script compiled into the image that runs as the image's default `ENTRYPOINT` but that accepts a normal `CMD` as the actual main container process.  The simplest form of this would look like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# run migrations
php artisan migrate

# run the main container `CMD` (or an execution-time override)
exec "$@"
```

The one complication here is that setting `ENTRYPOINT` in a Dockerfile also resets the `CMD`, and the `php:apache` images come with a default `CMD`.  If you look at the [Docker Hub `php` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and then click through to the "`Dockerfile` links" page, you can find the official [Dockerfile for `php:8.0-apache`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/41c9ad0b43a50bbf46564f27779a01105df49b9a/8.0/bullseye/apache/Dockerfile).  If you look at the end of that file, it has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, so you need to replicate both of these in your setup.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

...

# run the main container CMD, via the original ENTRYPOINT
exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    this is the base image's ENTRYPOINT
```

```bash
# Dockerfile

...

WORKDIR /var/www

# copy the application source and supporting scripts into the image
COPY ./ ./

# set the entrypoint to our wrapper script, and repeat the base
# image's command
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#   this is the base image's CMD
```

Now in your Compose setup, you don't need to set a `command:` or `entrypoint:` for any of these containers, or mount the application code into the container; all of these details are already set in the image.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - 8001:80
        # no working_dir: or volumes:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        # no entrypoint:
volumes:
    dbdata:
        # empty
# no need for top-level networks: in most applications
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql container does not have PHP installed.
You need to run the command in your "app" container.